# &http.Client in Golang, Need Explanation

Tags: go

I found the following code

client := &http.Client

What does & mean? What kind of value that client var receives

Comment: `client` here is a pointer to the instance of `http.Client`. `var client *http.Client; client = &http.Client{..}`

Comment: [& is the address operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators). 
 The posted code is invalid. Taking the address of a type makes no sense.  Perhaps you are asking about `client := &http.Client{}` or `var client http.Client`.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go which explains basic language constructs.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Answer (score 4):

`&` is the "pointer to" operator, similar to [c](/questions/tagged/c). The `client` variable holds a pointer to the value of `http.Client`.

Answer (score 1):

`client` here is a pointer to the instance of `http.Client`.

It is same as:

```
var client *http.Client
client = &http.Client{...}
```